# Windows Phone 8.1 camera app prevent pin passcode from showing

Tags: windows-phone-8, windows-phone-8.1

In WP8.1, one can write a phone camera app which is used when the camera button is tapped (to replace the out-of-the-box Windows Camera App or Lumia Camera App)

Setting the camera app works fine, and launching it with the camera button works too, however, when a pin / passcode is set on the device, it first asks for the passcode / pin before showing the camera app. For the Lumia and Microsoft Camera app, they get launched without asking for the pin.

Do you have any idea why?

Thanks